# Float aspx menu on center of screen during horizontal scroll

Tags: asp.net, menu

I have a static aspx menu. (horizontal)

I have content on the screen the sometimes requires horizontal scroll.

I would like to keep the menu the width of the visable screen and centered while scrolling. AKA. the menu would stay in the same position on the screen even when the user scrolls.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm relaly looking for simple. Even something that would just keep the menu items aligned left would work for me. So the menu bar can go all the way accross, but the items in it would align left, so the right most part fo the menu bar would be empty on longer screens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one..it works well for me. It uses jquery & css. I put it on my masterpages.

http://net.tutsplus.com/html-css-techniques/creating-a-floating-html-menu-using-jquery-and-css/

You can adjust the css to position it wherever you like

Comment: I tried using some jwuery stuff before. could never get it to work.... There's not any way to do this with the standard menu?

Comment: Also i need a horizonal menu. That is not at the very top of the page. There is a header above it. Also I don't need it to float. I really just need a header that stays where it is, that is just always centered while it is visable. Although I suppose that I found need it to float horizontally....